# Store result of http request to variable

Tags: node.js

Hi I get problem to fetch content of web page. Please see my code below

```
var http = require('http');
var html = '';
var options = {
    host: 'dev.gunship.io',
    path: '/node.html'
};
callback = function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        html += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        //console.log(html);
    });
};
http.request(options, callback).end();
console.log(html);
```

Why my console not log anything..?
Thank you for any help

Comment: because `http.request` is working async, when your logging the html var the callback has not happened yet.

Comment: Ya you are correct.. I still confused with how async work.. You have idea so I can print out the output after this code http.request(options, callback).end(); ? I need to store to the variable and return it.
Thanks in advance